# Why is the headers property of an http.IncomingMessage non-enumerable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server, enumerable

Say I create a node server with the following:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  // req is an IncomingMessage
}
```

I [believe](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#event-request) the first param, `req`, is an instance of `IncomingMessage`

I know this instance has a [headers](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#messageheaders) property.

If I do `Object.keys(req)`, however, I do *not* see the `headers` key.  I assume this is because this the `headers` property is non-enumerable.

Question is - *why*?  Why is `headers` not enumerable whereas `rawHeaders` is?  Is this just how it is, or is there a specific reason / benefit to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Click on the little "History" thing on the very page you linked

Comment: Could always use propertyIsEnumerable to figure out whether your suspicion is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously, in Node.js versions before 15.1.0, the req.headers property was an own property of the IncomingMessage object. It was readily available and enumerable, meaning you could directly access it and iterate over it using Object.keys() or a for…in loop. However, starting from version 15.1.0, this behavior was altered.

The req.headers property is no longer an own property of the IncomingMessage object. Instead, it is lazily computed using an accessor property on the prototype. This means that when you access req.headers, it is now computed on-the-fly and not stored as a direct property on the req object.

for more details you can go here : https://medium.com/@apoorva.gcet/understanding-the-change-in-req-headers-in-node-js-version-15-1-0-and-above-dbcb3ea812a0